# Change the name of the CSV File Automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, cmd

> sqlcmd -S PC03 -d db_test -E -o "test\MyData.csv" ^
>       -Q "[test2]" ^
>       -W -w 999 -s","

I would like to change the name of the file into "20150512". The name of the file should be today's date.

I do not know how to do it.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sqlcmd -S servername -d dbtest -E -o c:\asdf\%date:~0,10%.csv ^ -Q
>   "[dbname].[sp]" ^ -W -w 999 -s","

Answer (score 0):

try this to generate YYYYMMDD format output file. (append your filename)

**Edited:**

```
sqlcmd -S PC03 -d db_test -E -o c:\test-%datetime:~0,4%-%datetime:~4,2%-%datetime:~6,2%.csv
```

Comment: Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file 5-11_5-_20.csv 
<Reason: Access is denied

Comment: Please take a look at the new applied picture

Comment: Is it possible to create the csv file to test map? if yes, how?

Comment: You dont have permission to create a file. Please run the command with administrator privileges.

Comment: How should I write the path in order make the file to be created in the map "c:\test"?

Comment: c:\test-%datetime:~0,4%-%datetime:~4,2%-%datetime:~6,2%.csv

Comment: Reason: The filename, direcotry name, or volumen label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Please give some valuable path ,, dont blindly give C:\test: if you wish to do so,, create TEST folder under C disk,, then you can use it

Comment: Then I create a new map named "abc" (c:\abc)

Comment: I still retrieve the same error. Have you tried your code in your computer?